# When reviewing you should see what others have voted for so far

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

At the moment, when reviewing an edit, you do not have any indication of what others are thinking about the question, at least, not until you click 'reject'. Only then, once you are already going down the route of rejecting do you see what others are thinking. I see many edits that should be rejected but are already approved, which I assume is people rushing through to accept edits (perhaps a downside to badges, but let's not get sidetracked).

I propose that when reviewing an edit, you are shown how many people have so far rejected the edit. This data is already viewable to a reviewer, it is just one step away. Hopefully this will make people think about approving posts if others have already rejected the edit. As I see it, this will hopefully make people more willing to reject edits, and if it turns out that the edit really did need to be made, someone else will surely propose it.

I in no way pretend to think that this will make the review system perfect, but it do belive it will help towards that.

Comment: So wait, you're saying the legitimate edits being rejected by robo reviewers seeing people already rejecting and rejecting themselves is an acceptible casualty of this because "if it turns out that the edit really did need to be made, someone else will surely [re]propose it". This feels like building failure into the system

Comment: Opposed to now where robo reviers blindly approve, resulting in edits that shouldn't have been made being accepted and thus these edits never getting undone.

Comment: I don't think is a duplicate really. But this probably should be closed now. Reading that other question, it's clear the view "Review blind to what others think, and never know if you are 'right' in your decision"

Comment: Even a count on the Reject button at least would say that blindly approving the edit is another indication someone is asleep on the Approve button

Answer (score 10):

The review queue isn't about the opinions of others, it is about the action you want to take against a post. If you are unsure on which action to take you shouldn't be looking to lean on the opinions of others - there is a skip button for a reason.

There are already enough people who simply click accept or reject on everything - adding the ability to see how other people have voted while reviewing isn't going to aid this situation at all.

At certain reputation levels, and indeed, in certain review queues, it is possible to get an understanding of how other people have voted:

- When closing, clicking "Close" will show you all of the other close votes except where a question has been flagged and you're the first person to arrive at the question
- When editing, clicking on "Reject" will show you what other reject votes have already been cast, in the instance that there are any edit rejects in place already

Additionally, at certain reputation levels (I believe this is 10k+) it is possible to see all other actions taken by going to "Recent Reviews" on the "History" tab. I'm not actually sure what the reputation level required is to view these (I can see them all on Arqade where I have >20k but I can't see them on MSO where I have enough reputation to use the Close Votes queue, for example).

Comment: The problem is though, too many edits are just being accepted, accepted, accepted. The idea is not to have people fall back on the views of others, but to make them think twice about blindly accepting. And yes, it is about the views of others. What one person considered a substation change another might think is too trivial.

Comment: @thecoshman Your idea is likely to make that worse: already accepted --> I'll accept too. Already rejected --> I'll reject too

Comment: Except I am not proposing that you see how many accepta have so far been granted.

Comment: @thecoshman And the other half of the problem?  Already rejected --> I'll reject too

Comment: As I said in the question, if the edit really need to be made, someone else will propose it.

Comment: @RichardTingle if we could see other users' votes, it would actually become worthwhile to take the time and write a custom reject message. Also I don't buy it will make the problem worse - the idiots accept everything anyway, and the good reviewers are unlikely to be biased by existing votes as they know how many garbage reviews there are. That said, maybe a 2-step process would make sense - let people vote, then show others' decisions and ask users whether they want to change theirs

Comment: @Pëkka since it's already the case that you can see other people's suggested edit reject votes, you'd expect if this would actually happen that it already would be (but isn't...)

Comment: @flyk but the problem is, as I see it, is that people will have to have already made up their mind that they wanted to reject an edit. Seeing the other votes only helps decide *why* to reject the edit.

Comment: @thecoshman I feel you may still be missing the point - it's not about what other people do, it's about what *your opinion* on what to do is. You were given access to the review queue and it's your responsibility to take ownership of your own choices while acting in the review queues. Just following other people's decisions is **not** the correct way to review.

Comment: @Flyk I agree with that, but blindly following is no worse than blindly accepting everything. You seem be living in some fantasy land where the only people reviewing are those who take the time to actually think about the quality of the edit.

Comment: @thecoshman wrong - I'm aware that there are issues with the review system. I'm saying that this proposed change would make them worse, not better.  My post actually says **There are already enough people who simply click accept or reject on everything** so I'm not sure how you can conclude that I'm living in some fantasy world where this doesn't happen.